# What is the equivalent of index exists in pyelasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

The index exists for REST:

```
 curl -XHEAD -i 'http://localhost:9200/twitter'
```

What is the equivalent of above in pyelasticsearch ? The Api documentation doesnt contain this.

Answer (score 4):

In Python, you can see whether an index exists using the [`exists` function](http://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.org/en/master/api.html#elasticsearch.Elasticsearch.exists)

```
self.client.indices.exists('twitter')
```

**UPDATE**

With the pyelasticsearch library, there is no exposed function for doing it, but you can create one yourself that does it very easily:

```
client.send_request('HEAD', ['twitter'])
```

And then check that you get HTTP 200 OK in the response.

Comment: I am asking about [pyelasticsearch](https://pyelasticsearch.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) BTW, this doesnt work

Comment: No @val. I used requests module itself. That returns the response object, which I used to validate it.

Comment: Also correctly applies to `opensearch-py`!

Comment: The link is to the wrong `.exists()`!

Answer (score 0):

We can use: `es.indices.get_aliases(index_name)`.

It will return index and its alias if index exits else it throws `index_not_found_exception`.